# iOS 13 Background Tasks Not working in Release Mode

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, background-task

I tried to use the **iOS 13 background tasks**, with the Apple Example:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks

But the application works perfectly fine if i use in debug mode(Using the below apple commands provided)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting_and_terminating_tasks_during_development

On a release mode(with out console commands) **not even once** **triggered the background** tasks, i tried

1. Connecting the application to Xcode with breakpoints.
2. Giving a local notification when background tasks trigger.
3. Using Userdefaults to keep count of number of Event Triggers.

None of them gave me an answer, Tried for whole day.

So wanted to understand, if any one has used iOS 13 background tasks, could please help me guide what im missing.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say debug build, are you testing not attached to the debugger? Being attached to the debugger changes the app lifecycle (keeps the app running in the background). If you’re comparing attached to the debugger vs not being attached to the debugger, the issue is likely unrelated to the build settings, but rather whether you are attached to the debugger or not. Try your debug build being started from the device, with Xcode not running at all.

Comment: Hi @Rob, Sorry for confusion. Edited my question to avoid confusion.
Debug Build, i mean to say that using the debug commands of apple provided by apple.(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting_and_terminating_tasks_during_development) 
I have used it with connecting the device to Xcode.


I tried the build without attaching to Xcode and this didnt trigger any background tasks.

Comment: Regarding the release test, I’m assuming you did _not_ force-quit the app, as that will prevent any background operation.

Comment: I tried many scenarios, just normal background without force Quit.
With Forcequit as wel.. But nothing triggered me the background tasks.